# Export SQL database (all tables) from remote server

Tags: sql, database-backups, sql-server-2005-express

I'm current using a 3rd party product, which uses an SQL Server database. I've been asked to take a copy of the database for our own backup/security purposes, but I'm having trouble.

To access the database I'm currently logging into one of my companies servers using remote desktop, where SQL Server 2005 Express is installed. Using that instance of SQL Server I then connect to the 3rd party's SQL server.

when I execute Tasks -> Back Up..., it appears to work, but the files are stored locally on the remote SQL Databases server, which my IT teams tells me is expected.

I tried using Tasks -> Generate Scripts... but the option to "Script Data" isn't available, either because it's SQL Server 2005 Express, or because the database is remote (not sure which, but probably one of those).

I've tried other things that I can't recall at the moment, and I'm out of ideas.

Can anyone suggest something that will let me get a 'local' copy of the remote databases table structure AND data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Generate Scripts wizard is unavailable because you are using a very old version of Management Studio Express. The 2012 version will work just fine against 2005 instances, but there is no longer an Express edition anyway, because all of the SSMS features are now available without any license.

Download the latest versions here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms

I list downloads for the older versions at the bottom of this post:

https://blogs.sentryone.com/team-posts/latest-builds-management-studio/

Comment: I selected this as the answer. I used 2005 as this is what was available on the server. However, I did install 2008 locally (not express) and the option to download structure AND data is available, and currently running. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Backups do generate locally.  That is to be expected, as your team has already told you.  You can generate it locally and then download it with a tool such as an FTP client.  I highly recommend Redgate tools.  See http://www.red-gate.com/products/dba/sql-backup/ It's a great tool and has some network backup options built in to ship your backups elsewhere.  If it's a one-time thing, Redgate also has tools for that too, e.g. SQL Compare and SQL Data Compare.

The solution you pick really depends on how frequently you have to run and download backups locally and how big the DB is.

Comment: Unfortuantely I have no access to the DB Server, so cannot get teh file once it's downloaded. Neither do I have info on the network used by the 3rd party, so I cannot save the file via the network to an FTP site. This is a one-time deal, so Aaron's solution works best for me. Thanks though